# RPi drives motors on L298n for a few seconds and then stops

Tags: pi-zero, dc-motor

I am trying to make a Robotic Car using 4 motors and L298n for a motor driver. The motor specifications as listed on the purchase site are given below:

- Operating Voltage: 3V~6V DC
- Gear Ratio 1:48
- No-load speed(5V): about 208RPM
- Rated Torque: 0.8 Kg.cm @ 5V
- Load current: 170mA (when it is 4.5V)
- Size: 70 x 23  x 18 mm
- Weight:28g
- Shaft Length: 10 mm
- Shaft Type: 6 mm, Double-D

I have made the connections as show in the image below :
[image]

(I have removed all jumpers)

and following is the code I am using the run the motors

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(7,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(11,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(13,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(15,gpio.OUT)

gpio.output(7,True)
gpio.output(11,True)

while True:
    gpio.output(13,True)
    gpio.output(15,False)
    time.sleep(2)
    gpio.output(13,False)
    gpio.output(15,True)
    time.sleep(2)
    gpio.output(13,False)
    gpio.output(15,False)
    time.sleep(2)
```

**Problem** : When I run the script, The motors spins first cycle of the loop and the stops spinning.

**What I tried** : The motors only start spinning again for another cycle if I disconnect and reconnect the ground cable that connects Rpi ground to L298n ground. This problem doesn't occur when I am providing 12V 1A power supply(reads as 20V DC on my multimeter, I don't know why though) instead of the 4 x AA 1.5V batteries which I want to use.

**Question** : Is this a problem of power supply or am I doing something else wrong? I have tried multiple tutorials on the youtube but couldn't figure out the problem.

I am stuck with this for a week now. I can provide with more information, if you can specify what you want in the comments....

Comment: Disconnecting Gnd is a good way of destroying the Pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description the batteries can not supply enough power for a
sustained period.  They are drained after four seconds of use until you give them a period of rest when they recover enough for a few more seconds.

You need more powerful batteries or smaller motors.

Comment: Thank you. Supposing I use 6V, how would I calculate the required battery specifications, would required Ampere rating be 170mA*4 = 680mA?